# Can I freeze ricotta hand pies?

Tags: freezing, cheese, pie

I want to make little hand pies with apple and ricotta, bake them, and then freeze them to thaw for afternoon snacks. Any advice? Will that work?

Comment: We'll need more information (e.g. what's a "hand pie"? any other ingredients?).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work. I do this for a friend who hates to bake but loves apple (or nectarine)-and-cheese pies. Dry cottage cheese will also work.